# Add a custom CRON job from the command line?

Tags: cron

Debian seems to have directories for cron jobs such as `/etc/cron.daily` and `/etc/cron.hourly`, but is there a way for me to automate editing, removing, and updating cron jobs from an automated script?

I'm working on a Docker container and I'd like to allow the user to specify the cron frequency of a specific task to be run in the background. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If these are individual user cron jobs, you should use the `crontab` command to update their crontabs, not use `/etc/cron.XXXly`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you want to use `/etc/cron.d`, where you can place full system crontab entries (as you'd put in /etc/crontab) in their own file. Then you can set the intervals, enable, and disable it by manipulating that file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!